# When trying to get the type of an object property typeof() always returns "object"

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m working on a **ModelMapper** to map API responses to a model. There I need to find out the type of a property of the target model.

**Example for the target model:**

```
export interface IProduct {
  id?: number,
  title: string,
  prices: Price[]
}

export class Product implements IProduct {

  id: number
  title: string
  prices: Price[]

  constructor() {
    this.id = null
    this.title = null
    this.prices = []
  }
}
```

In the ModelMapper I want to **iterate over the properties** of this class and find out, which **type the properties have**. That will allow me to fetch and map sub-models like "Price" in the example above.

**My question:**
Is there a way to **iterate over the properties of a class** (not an instantiated object) and get the expected type for each property? In the example above that should be:

- id: number
- title: string
- prices: Prices[]

Comment: The typing extensions are suggestions that are used by your editor.  They have no runtime presence.

Comment: To add to Tim's comment, it's worth remembering that you're still writing Javascript. The interfaces that Typescript allows you to use completely disappear at the point the ts is compiled to js.

Comment: For your ModelMapper you could provide your entities a type property, which holds the type name to be used in the mapper.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes absolute sense... :)